# Facebook C# SDK v6 - How to post graph action?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Looking for some help on posting an open graph action using v6 of the SDK. I have been scouring for a couple of days, and can't find any examples of how to do this. So far I have:

```
protected void btnDyno_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookSDKInterface fbData = new FacebookSDKInterface();
        var fb = new FacebookClient(fbData.FacebookAccessToken);

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.appnamespace = "thedynoroom";
        parameters.action = "added";
        parameters.object_name = "dyno_run";
        parameters.object_url = "http://thedynoroom.com/DesktopModules/Incite/InciteCore/FBObject.aspx";

        try
        {
            dynamic result = fb.Post("me/", parameters);

            lblPostMessageResult.Text = result;
            txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException ex)
        {
            lblPostMessageResult.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

I know this is not correct, as I was just guessing as I was unable to find any documentation on this specifically. Is there any more documentation other than what is on http://csharpsdk.org?

Thanks in advance for the help!
Chad

UPDATE: Ok, figured it finally...
If, when in your facebook developer graph dashboard, the Get Code link for your action looks like this:

```
curl -F 'access_token=blahblahblah' \
 -F 'dyno_run=http://samples.ogp.me/266692056752346' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/thedynoroom:add'
```

Then your code should look like this:

```
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.dyno_run = "http://samples.ogp.me/266692056752346";

        try
        {
            dynamic result = fb.Post("me/thedynoroom:add", parameters);

            lblPostMessageResult.Text = result;
            txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        }
```

Note that in the "parameters.xxxxxxx" the xxxxx is = to your action name.

Now I just need to figure out how to parse the JSON result :)

Comment: How do you pass in real metadata though? You're referencing the sample metadata.

Comment: @simon.d - The URL that is simply the url of the object that you want to post about, i.e. the recipe detail page (in keeping with their documentation example). eg: Dim dicFBPostParams As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()<br />
            dicFBPostParams.Add(YOUROBJECT, URL to your Object page)<br />dynamic result = fb.Post("me/YOURAPPNAMESPACE:YOUACTION", dicFBPostParams);

Comment: Okay so the object has to be hosted by my server?

Comment: Right. Let's say you have a site that sells baseball hats. In the facebook app, you'd configure an action, let's say "buy" and an object for that action, let's say "hat". Then on the detail page for each hat that you sell, you need to have the og tags (og:title, og:description, etc) generated in the header of that page dynamically from your database to reflect that hat. Now when you do a post to FB for this action/object url, it goes to the object URL of the page and reads these og:tags to know what data to put on the post.

Comment: To generate the page header info, here is some sample pseudo code...(not enough room or avail formatting in comments to display all): in page load, create a dictionary and populate it with all your og tag data: dicFBTags.Add("og:description", dt.Rows(0)("OG_Description")); then loop through the library to add these to the page header: Dim fbTag As HtmlMeta = New HtmlMeta()
                fbTag.Attributes.Add("property", pair.Key)
                fbTag.Content = pair.Value ' dont HtmlEncode() string. HtmlMeta already escapes characters.
                Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, fbTag)

Comment: Thanks Chad. That helps. How about videos? If I want my user to be able to upload videos from my app and have them appear in the Open Graph, does my website have to host the videos? Or can I use FB itself or YouTube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer under UPDATE above.