# Posting items/stories to face book users walls

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to automatically post items to facebook users' feeds using Facebook Graph.
My example is a user of my app earns points. In Facebook dev centre, I have created an object "Points" and an action "earn"

I found the existing question [Facebook C# SDK v6 - How to post graph action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985677/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-v6-how-to-post-graph-action) and have implemented the following code, but no posts are appearing. (code is currently in a test ActionResult, but will eventaully be bundled into business logic, and called form an Azure service that works out when points are earned)

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("{auth-token}");
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.points = "{url}";
        parameters.explicitly_shared = true;

        try
        {
            dynamic result = fb.Post("me/my-app-name:earn", parameters);

            return Content(result.ToString());
        }
        catch(FacebookApiException ex)
        {
            return Content(ex.Message);
    }
```

Note: The URL I am passing in has got the correct (I believe anyway) OG meta tags, releated to the object and action I am using.

I get the following response ({integer-id} is the id I am getting back)

**{"id":"{integer-id}"}**

Do I then have to do another "post" with this Id to actually get the item to appear in the users feed?

Any help would be hugely welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important:** Not every published action is actually displayed on a users timeline or your friends newsfeed! In fact, most custom actions are not.

However, if you get an actual post-ID as a result, this means that the action was definitely published successful! You can check the published in your browser at:

https://www.facebook.com/{user-id}/activity/{action-id}

Where {action-id} = the ID you got as a result, and {user-id} is your numeric user-ID or username.

You can also check https://www.facebook.com/{username}/allactivity to see **all published activity**.

Also, you should consider using the Scores- & Achievements-APIs for your usecase, they are probably better than using a custom action:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/scores/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/achievements/

Comment: Thanks Michael, so it is appearing under allactivity. However, the format that is displayed is wrong. I added an extra "caption" to display the description under the title. When viewing on the https://www.facebook.com/{user-id}/activity/{action-id} it displays correctly, but doesn't include the description in my activity?

Comment: That's correct by design: in the activity log, actions are only displayed with their title & thumbnail!

All the rest is only displayed in the detail-view (https://www.facebook.com/{user-id}/activity/{action-id}) or when an action actually appears in Newsfeed or Timeline (which is dynamically decided by Facebooks algorithm, f.e. actions using user_message or explicit sharing are normally displayed on Timeline)

Comment: OK, great, so the "full view" as formatted in developer centre is really only displayed to other users (my friends) timeline.. Guess that makes sense, and also explains why I can only see one instance of that post in a colleagues timeline, even though I posted it several times in mine.

Comment: That's only party true - the full view is both potentially appearing in your friends Newsfeed, and the publishing users own Timeline.

But, as said, there's some algorith at work deciding which actions are "worthy" on which place. You can tune your actions reach by using special OG-features (user message, explicit sharing, adding geo, adding photos). I've made some slides last december about this topic:

http://www.slideshare.net/socialisten/all-facebook-devconen20121123