# Facebook OG Post not appearing correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the method outlined in another question I made, [Posting items/stories to face book users walls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477792/posting-items-stories-to-face-book-users-walls) to make OG posts.

A post appears in my timeline, however, it's not displaying correctly.
I have setup the format in Facebook developer centre.

[image: example story]

However, the post doesn't include the {object.description} xxxxx and Points Earned sections

[image: Example of post]

I am setting the OG tags on the page that the post relates too as follows:

```
  <meta property="fb:app_id"             content="{fb-id}" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"               content="{app-name}:points" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"                content="{the url}" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"              content="New points earned .. ?" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"              content="{url-to-image}" /> 
  <meta property="og:description"        content="You just earned 6 points?" /> 
  <meta property="{app-name}:nopoints"   content="4" />
```

The post is taking the og:title, and og:description from the meta tags correctly, but is ignoring my test "xxxxx" on the page, as well as not displaying the "Points Earned" section.

I can preview the post using the following URL format https://www.facebook.com/{facebook-id}/activity/{activity-id} using the ID I get returned after making the post, and it displays correctly there: (ignore that fact that is says both 4 and 6 points)

[image]

For completeness, I am using the follow code to make the actual post:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("{access-token}");
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.points = "{url}";
        parameters.explicitly_shared = true;
        parameters.nopoints = 4;
        parameters.description = "my description";
        try
        {
            dynamic result = fb.Post("me/{app-name}:earn", parameters);
        }
        catch(FacebookApiException ex)
        {
        }
```

Am I missing something here? Does the post display differently else where on Facebook? 
Do I have to make the actual post differently? Include other parameters etc?

Cheers